# Screws for HP 2159M Monitor Base

Tags: display, hp-pavilion, screws

Can anyone help me with what type/size screws an [HP Pavilion 2159m](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01679486) monitor uses for its base?

We moved to a new house a few weeks ago, and I disassembled the monitor base while packing, but misplaced the mounting screws. Now I want to put the monitor back together, but I realized I have no mounting screws so I will need to buy new ones.

I tried searching online for this info, but couldn't find anything. The below image  - from HP's support page for End-of-life disassembly - shows what screws I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display mount is VESA (MIS-D) 4-hole 100 mm x 100 mm as mentioned in the [link](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01679486) you've provided in your question. This specific type of mount uses M4 type screws meaning the hole depth is 10mm. You can get this type of screws on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/4x-M4-10mm-TV-or-Computer-Monitor-Stand-Bracket-Mounting-Screws-VESA-/221421498553) or ask in a local computer hardware shop (they usually have plenty of those laying around).

Comment: Thank you, I will go to my local store and see if they have any,